# How can I get escaped URL from parseJSON result in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

My current code uses json and the returned result looks like this:

```
{"1379973204_SimonHead.JPG":"http:\/\/localhost\/wp-content\/plugins\/userpro\/uploads\/temp\/1379973204_SimonHead.JPG"}
```

My question is how can I find and retrieve the URL from that result? Also note the slashes, I want to be able to get a clean formatted url to use it in my app.

I got the above data by doing: `data = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));`

Any help is appreciated

Comment: As far as I can see, only the '/' are being escaped. Doesn't a `str.replace('\\/', '/')` work for you?

Comment: `jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));` This line, you're stringifying, then parsing instantly. You're JSON is most likely already parsed.

Comment: Ok how can I get that value itself? i mean how to get it from data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). It will return a javascript object.  Most browsers support this natively now, so there's no need to use jQuery.parseJSON http://caniuse.com/#feat=json

If your url is still escaped, you are double encoding your data somewhere.

So for example:

```
var data = JSON.parse(yourjson);
var url = data["1379973204_SimonHead.JPG"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Stringify your json, and then use a regex

```
var string = JSON.stringify('{"1379973204_SimonHead.JPG":"http:\/\/localhost\/wp-content\/plugins\/userpro\/uploads\/temp\/1379973204_SimonHead.JPG"}');
var url = string.match("http:(.*\.[a-z]{3})")[0]
console.log(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing the following with your resultant data object:

```
var expectedURL = data["1379973204_SimonHead.JPG"].replace('\\/','/');
```

now doing a console.log(expectedURL) prints the following:

```
http://localhost/wp-content/plugins/userpro/uploads/temp/1379973204_SimonHead.JPG
```